# If $x$ is algebraic over a quotient field $K$ of $A$, then there exists an integral element $cx$ for some $A \ni c \neq 0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, fractions, integral-extensions, algebraic-equations

Let $A$ be a commutative ring, $K$ its quotient field and $x$ algebraic over $K$.  This means that there exists a polynomial $f(X)$ with coefficients in $K$ such that $f(x) = 0$.  In other words, if we write the coefficients of $f$ as $\dfrac{a_i}{b_i}, i = 0,.., n$, then we can multiply both sides of $f(x) = 0$ by $b = \prod_{i=0}^n b_i$ to achieve $f'(x) = 0$ where the coefficients of $f'$ can be viewed as elements of $A$.  How do we get this to be $f(cx)$ though?

Comment: $b f(X) \in A[X]$, its leading coefficient is $c$, then $c^{n-1} b f( X/c) $ is monic. What do you expect with $f'$ ?

Comment: Just write $x$ in the form $x=p/q$ with $p$ and $q$ coprime and you'll see what 
 polynomial that vanishes at $qx$.

Comment: Thanks @reuns  you're right.  So that makes sense.  $(b f)_n = a_n \prod_{i \neq n} b_i = c$ is the leading coefficient but doesn't that mean $(X/c)^n = X^n / c^n$ so we would indeed need $c^{n-1}$ to make it monic.  Thanks !

Comment: @mouthetics:  but $x$ is *algebraic* over $K$, so how do we know $x = p/q$?

Comment: @RobertLewis Sorry! I thought $x$ is in the quotient field of  $A$.